# Remove all content in an HTML table using the sed command

Tags: html, shell, unix, sed

I would like to remove everything in between `<table...</table>` including the two tags:

```
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" summary="">
    <tr>
    <td class="small-beige-item"> <a href="http://www.electoral-        
   </tbody>
   </table>
```

I am using

```
  sed 's/\<table[^<table]*\</table>//g'
```

But I get an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what's the output you expecting? is that you want to eliminate everything including <table * till </table>?

Comment: I'm confused. Your description sounds like you want to remove 0, small-beige-item and http... But your regex looks like its trying to remove the table. So what exactly do you want?

Comment: You could do it like this, if you can be bothered: http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.24

Comment: The idea was to remove that entire block of text. starting from <table... to </table> that includes all lines in between

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backup your file.

```
sed -ie '/<table.*>/,/<\/table>/d' filename
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.